# java method to convert List<String> to List<T> where T can be Integer or Long

Tags: java, generics

Given a `List<String>`, how to write a method to convert to it to `List<T>` where T can be `Integer` or `Long` but this is available at runtime only. Here is the code that I could come up with. It seems to work.

Is this the right way to do it?
Can it be simplified further?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1, 2, 3, 4";
    System.out.println(convertCSVStringToList(s, Integer.class));
    System.out.println(convertCSVStringToList(s, Long.class));
}

public static <T> List<T> convertCSVStringToList(String s, Class<T> type) {
    return Stream.of(s.split(","))
        .map(String::trim)
        .map(e -> valueOf(e, type))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}


private static <T> T valueOf(String s, Class<T> type) {
    T t = null;

    try {
        if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
            t = (T) Integer.valueOf(s);
        } else if (type.equals(Long.class)) {
            t = (T) Long.valueOf(s);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println(String.format("Cannot convert <%s> to type %s", s, type.getSimpleName()));
    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: Is the code throwing any error? what's the output? have you tried debugging it.

Comment: @mtk It works. Questions is more on if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: "Is this the right way to do it?" An if/else chain based on types inside a generic method is typically a sign that it's not the right way. Your code will have also generated unchecked cast warnings (which are safe, in this case; but it's a sign that the compiler is saying "I give up, you work out if this is correct or not").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than supplying a `Class<T>`, supply a `Function<String, T>` to  convertCSVStringToList(more generally, it can be a `Function<? super String, ? extends T>`), and remove your `valueOf` method:

```
public static <T> List<T> convertCSVStringToList(String s, Function<String, T> fn) {
```

Invoking this `Function` in the stream chain:

```
return Stream.of(s.split(","))
    .map(String::trim)
    .map(fn)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And invoke `convertCSVStringToList` like:

```
System.out.println(convertCSVStringToList(s, Integer::valueOf));
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing a class, which means you need to deal with each case individually in your `valueOf` method, you could pass a function that transforms the String to the desired object.

```
System.out.println(convertCSVStringToList(s, Integer::valueOf));

public static <T> List<T> convertCSVStringToList(String s, Function<String, T> transformer) {
  ...
    .map(String::trim)
    .map(transformer)
  ...
}
```

Comment: What about `NumberFormatException`? In OP's code it maps to null.